# ContourPlot not showing all curves

Tags: plotting

For some reason ContourPlot does not show all the curves (I am using Mathematica 12 Home Edition on Windows). For example 
consider

```
elPotP[q_, {x1_, y1_}][x_, y_] := Module[{r},
  r = EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {x1, y1}];
  q /r]
```

If I do

```
ContourPlot[
 elPotP[-1, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elPotP[1, {1, 0}][x, y], {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, Contours -> Range[-4, 4, 0.5], 
 ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

you can see that not all the 17 curves are plotted

[image]

But if I do

```
c = Table[
   ContourPlot[
    elPotP[-1, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elPotP[1, {1, 0}][x, y] == k, {x, -2, 
     2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ContourShading -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 50], {k, -4, 4, 0.5}];
Show[c]
```

Then all of them are shown.

[image]

Why is that? Is there a way to force ContourPlot to show all the curves I want?

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @march mentioned in comments, it's a `PlotRange` issue that can be solved by adding `PlotRange -> All`.

Perhaps your formatting choices happened to make it more difficult to spot in the `ContourPlot`. A version of your `ContourPlot` including color shading  (i.e. with the `ContourShading -> None` removed) may have highlighted the issue more clearly, with the white areas in the following plot indicating clipping:

[image: shaded contour plot with automatic plotrange]

Compare this to the equivalent 3D plot generated using the automatic `PlotRange` settings:

```
Plot3D[
  elPotP[-1, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elPotP[1, {1, 0}][x, y],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}
]
```

[image: 3D plot of the same function, showing the clipped peaks with automatic PlotRange]

You can clearly see the clipping caused by the automated plot range determination; this is because of the "spikiness" of these peaks:

```
Plot3D[
  elPotP[-1, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elPotP[1, {1, 0}][x, y],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: complete 3d plot showing the spiky peaks]

`ContourPlot` probably has internal routines similar to `Plot3D`'s to determine an appropriate choice of plot range, which cause it to ignore the contours that would fall within the clipped region of the spikes.

Once you add `PlotRange -> All` to the `ContourPlot`, those regions are considered as well, and the missing contour lines appear:

```
ContourPlot[
  elPotP[-1, {-1, 0}][x, y] + elPotP[1, {1, 0}][x, y],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
  Contours -> Range[-4, 4, 0.5],
  ContourShading -> None,
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: contour plot with all requested contour lines]

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: @Emmet You are very welcome!